# Spring boot Startup Error

Tags: spring-boot

When I try to run the spring boot application I am getting the below error

```
starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-05-03 10:50:09.457 ERROR 4909 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:     If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: Is `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` included in your pom.xml? It will assume that you will be dealing with a data store.

Comment: pls post snippet of your pom or gradle file and also your application.properties

Comment: Have you included `spring.datasource.url` in your application.properties or yml file?

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are correct in case you want to use a non-embedded data source. In case you want to use an embedded data source, you will only need to add the following dependency to your *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use the embedded data source in your tests, then change the scope to *test* instead of *runtime*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want auto-configuration of datasource, then place the configuration details in `application.properties` file. Something like this(configuration for MySQL)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```