# How can I connect my SpringBoot app with MySQL database?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I tried to set in the application.properties the URL, but I have this error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/mysql/migration
```

Comment: Please share the `pom.xml` contents. It seems that it can not load the mysql connector library.

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the error

Comment: validate your pom.xml with appropriate mysql lib.

Comment: You're missing the MySQL driver. With that set correctly you can delete all your other config apart from URL, username and password. Not least because most of it is wrong anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot Startup Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147762/spring-boot-startup-error)